# Базовая аутентификация PHP (выход из аккаунта)

Tags: php

```
<?php
if(empty($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']))
{
    header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="123"');
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorised');
    exit();
}

$key = false;

if($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] === '1')
    $key = true;

if(empty($key))
{
    header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="123"');
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorised');
    exit();
}
```

?>

Есть код аутентификации. Как сделать кнопку выход, чтобы после ее нажатия снова выскакивало окошко для авторизации?

Comment: В поиске можно найти вопрос и ответ на него: [несессионная деавторизация](http://hashcode.ru/questions/126976/)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В файле где выводится форма авторизации делай проверку, авторизован пользователь или нет. Если нет - выводи форму авторизации, если да - выводи кнопку выхода. Данные из формы авторизации из из формы с кнопкой выхода отправляй на один этот php-скрипт.

Comment: как выход сделать????????????

Comment: $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] = 0 //попробуйте